# Product attributes Re-indexing not working in magento 1.9.2.2

Tags: magento-1.9

I use magento 1.9.2.2 in that when i try to re-indexing data than "Product attributes" re-indexing not working it's display "There was a problem with re-indexing process" error.
I check solution from http://newsinfo-blog.blogspot.com/2015/11/solve-re-indexing-error-cannot.html and try all steps but not found any solution.
I create new reindex.php file as below

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app('admin');
umask(0);
for ($index = 1; $index load($index);  
  $process->reindexAll();  
}
?>
```

I found below error when i run that file on browser.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:
Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`catalog_product_index_eav`, CONSTRAINT `FK_OMNI_CAT_PRD_IDX_EAV_ENTT_ID_OMNI_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` )'
in /home/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0
/home/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
/home/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2
/home/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #3
/home/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4
/home/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(' in /home/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 235
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself recently. As it turns out, the previous developer of the site had created all of the database tables as MyISAM instead of InnoDB. When I upgraded from 1.8.1.0 to 1.9.2.2, I encountered this error because Magento failed to create the indices that it needed to function correctly. The only way to solve this issue was to run the [Magento Database Repair Tool](https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Magento+1.x+Database+Repair+Tool), which can be downloaded from the [Magento Download Page](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download). Perhaps it will help you as well.

## TLDR:

Your database is likely corrupt. Use the [Magento Database Repair Tool](https://wiki.magento.com/display/m1wiki/Magento+1.x+Database+Repair+Tool) to fix it.